# How often intermediate or advanced piano pieces use more than 61 keys?

Tags: piano, sheet-music, keyboard, classical-music

I am a self learning keyboard player and due to financial restrictions I am thinking about buying a 61-key keyboard. However I am worried by how this range can affect me in the near future as I advance.

I am worried about how often more advanced pieces tend to use more than 61 keys. The exact octaves don't bother me as usually keyboards with only 61 keys have transpose functions.